# JavaFx LineChart interrupt serie

Tags: javafx, charts

My software log some devices parameters and if the device is turned off i want to "interrupt" the series (i think i'll add a special value on the data to highlight a device off) and draw new points only when the device is turned on.

I'm using JavaFx LineChart (i don't want to change library)

Sorry for my very no talent using paint!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat each line before and after the break as a new series in the chart. You can keep the colors the same by assigning them to a custom css style class, and defining the class in your application's css file.

Comment: This can be a solution, the problem is that in one chart can be present multiple series and multiple interruption.

Comment: @RonSiven I like your idea but every time there is a break you will need a new series after that. I believe there is no a way to make it in LineChart. I can see only 3 options. The first one is to keep it simple and just set y values = 0 when the state is off , + you can hide the value indicator by passing a node and make it visible = false. The Second solution is to create a custom LineChart from scratch. And finally you could make a scatter chart and just add consecutive points giving the illusion of a line and if the state is off you will not connect them ( more like a hack)

Comment: @JKostikiadis I assure you, it really works great in a LineChart. I have used it in production in a commercial disk space monitoring application. Each time you add a data point to your series you check for a zero value. When that happens, you start a new series and set the color as appropriate.  I've had as many as 6 different colored application data series represented by many separately charted series with many breaks. One issue you run into, though, is if you use a legend. Each series is added to the default legend. I ended up rendering my own custom chart legend for that.

Comment: @RonSiven Yeah I am pretty sure that it's working fine, but to be honest i find it too complicated for no reason keeping track of the series , all the data etc etc. Sure it gives a better visual appearance but nothing more. About the legends you can simple remove one or more if you want easily ;). But all in all your suggestion is a good one.

Comment: The solution worked. But with hard work! having multiple chart with multiple "real" series with multiple "sub" series... Thanks Ron for the input