# How can I give two different styles for the same series of a line chart?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I would like to use JavaFX to assemble a line chart such that when there is no data to plot in a series, the space is empty. Something like that:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQL3c.png)

Notice that I would like to keep myself in the same series, just by changing your style in one part. But any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430961/javafx-linechart-interrupt-serie/46456562#46456562

Comment: It's a good method ... I had already thought of that. My concern is with memory, since I am plotting more than 250,000 points. I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx LineChart interrupt serie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430961/javafx-linechart-interrupt-serie)